# Is there a similar Elastic Beanstalk worker tier pattern in AWS OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs, aws-opsworks

We're wanting to move an application from AWS EB to AWS OpsWorks. The rough edge we're catching on is that we currently utilize the "worker tier" feature of EB. Is there anything similar to this design pattern in OpsWorks, or would we need to build a SQS based-client that sits on our previous worker-tier servers and mimics the worker-tier-client behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to build sqs client yourself. Opsworks doesn't have sqs-specific layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another [layer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinglayers.html) to your OpsWorks stack. Use one layer for your app and another layer for the worker since they likely have different attributes and may diverge over time.

Comment: Do you get any of the benefit of an SQS/HTTP message distributor that the EB worker tier provides? This is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pysqsd(http://github.com/flovilmart/pysqsd) as a worker client.
I use it in production, it's stable and running fine, and highly configurable!

Cheers